# Verification tests in Scala

Tags: unit-testing, scala, testng, verification, mockito

I want to make some verification in my test, but it never fails

```
import org.testng.annotations.Test
import org.specs.Specification
import org.specs.mock.Mockito
import org.mockito.Matchers._

class Tests extends Specification with Mockito{
  class Foo {
    def bar(){}
  }
  @Test def simplestTest() {
    val t = mock[Foo]
    t.bar()
    there was one(t).bar()   //pass
  }
  @Test def simplestFailTest() {
    val t = mock[Foo]
    there was one(t).bar()  //pass
  }
  @Test def testFail() {
    assert(false)           //fails
  }
}
```

I'm run it as TestNG tests. Where I'm wrong?

Comment: I have a vague recollection of needing to have some sort of assertion after a mock assertion. Try putting an `assert(true)` after `there was one(t).bar()` and see if that changes anything.

Comment: @Daniel C. Sobral, unfortunately it did not change anything

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't seem that specs supports running tests with TestNG: http://code.google.com/p/specs/wiki/RunningSpecs

Comment: One thing you can do is write your tests as TestNG tests and use the specs2 traits for better matching/mocking: http://etorreborre.github.com/specs2/guide/org.specs2.guide.Matchers.html#Reusing+matchers+outside+of+specs2

Comment: @Eric, Are there are any issues with supporting TestNG or it's just  not done yet?